# hyperparameter issues with SKlearn's Logistic regression in a Sagemaker Docker Script

Tags: python-3.x, docker, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I have been trying to translate a working notebook of mine into something sagemaker can use. but I have been unable to get past this error while writing the training script.

```
2023-05-05 20:31:30 Starting - Starting the training job...
2023-05-05 20:31:45 Starting - Preparing the instances for training......
2023-05-05 20:32:42 Downloading - Downloading input data...
2023-05-05 20:33:12 Training - Downloading the training image..2023-05-05 20:33:48,193 sagemaker-containers INFO     Imported framework sagemaker_sklearn_container.training
2023-05-05 20:33:48,197 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
2023-05-05 20:33:48,245 sagemaker_sklearn_container.training INFO     Invoking user training script.
2023-05-05 20:33:48,415 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
2023-05-05 20:33:48,428 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
2023-05-05 20:33:48,442 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
2023-05-05 20:33:48,451 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Invoking user script
Training Env:
{
    "additional_framework_parameters": {},
    "channel_input_dirs": {
        "train": "/opt/ml/input/data/train"
    },
    "current_host": "algo-1",
    "framework_module": "sagemaker_sklearn_container.training:main",
    "hosts": [
        "algo-1"
    ],
    "hyperparameters": {
        "C": 1.0,
        "class_weight": null,
        "dualbool": false,
        "fit_intercept": true,
        "intercept_scaling": 1,
        "l1_ratio": null,
        "max_iter": 1000,
        "multi_class": "auto",
        "n_jobs": null,
        "penalty": "l2",
        "random_state": null,
        "solver": "lbfgs",
        "tol": 0.0001,
        "verbose": 0,
        "warm_start": false
    },
    "input_config_dir": "/opt/ml/input/config",
    "input_data_config": {
        "train": {
            "TrainingInputMode": "File",
            "S3DistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
            "RecordWrapperType": "None"
        }
    },
    "input_dir": "/opt/ml/input",
    "is_master": true,
    "job_name": "logisticregression-model-2023-05-05-20-31-29-013",
    "log_level": 20,
    "master_hostname": "algo-1",
    "model_dir": "/opt/ml/model",
    "module_dir": "s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-457933018994/logisticregression-model-2023-05-05-20-31-29-013/source/sourcedir.tar.gz",
    "module_name": "script",
    "network_interface_name": "eth0",
    "num_cpus": 2,
    "num_gpus": 0,
    "output_data_dir": "/opt/ml/output/data",
    "output_dir": "/opt/ml/output",
    "output_intermediate_dir": "/opt/ml/output/intermediate",
    "resource_config": {
        "current_host": "algo-1",
        "current_instance_type": "ml.m5.large",
        "current_group_name": "homogeneousCluster",
        "hosts": [
            "algo-1"
        ],
        "instance_groups": [
            {
                "instance_group_name": "homogeneousCluster",
                "instance_type": "ml.m5.large",
                "hosts": [
                    "algo-1"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "network_interface_name": "eth0"
    },
    "user_entry_point": "script.py"
}
Environment variables:
SM_HOSTS=["algo-1"]
SM_NETWORK_INTERFACE_NAME=eth0
SM_HPS={"C":1.0,"class_weight":null,"dualbool":false,"fit_intercept":true,"intercept_scaling":1,"l1_ratio":null,"max_iter":1000,"multi_class":"auto","n_jobs":null,"penalty":"l2","random_state":null,"solver":"lbfgs","tol":0.0001,"verbose":0,"warm_start":false}
SM_USER_ENTRY_POINT=script.py
SM_FRAMEWORK_PARAMS={}
SM_RESOURCE_CONFIG={"current_group_name":"homogeneousCluster","current_host":"algo-1","current_instance_type":"ml.m5.large","hosts":["algo-1"],"instance_groups":[{"hosts":["algo-1"],"instance_group_name":"homogeneousCluster","instance_type":"ml.m5.large"}],"network_interface_name":"eth0"}
SM_INPUT_DATA_CONFIG={"train":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"}}
SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR=/opt/ml/output/data
SM_CHANNELS=["train"]
SM_CURRENT_HOST=algo-1
SM_MODULE_NAME=script
SM_LOG_LEVEL=20
SM_FRAMEWORK_MODULE=sagemaker_sklearn_container.training:main
SM_INPUT_DIR=/opt/ml/input
SM_INPUT_CONFIG_DIR=/opt/ml/input/config
SM_OUTPUT_DIR=/opt/ml/output
SM_NUM_CPUS=2
SM_NUM_GPUS=0
SM_MODEL_DIR=/opt/ml/model
SM_MODULE_DIR=s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-457933018994/logisticregression-model-2023-05-05-20-31-29-013/source/sourcedir.tar.gz
SM_TRAINING_ENV={"additional_framework_parameters":{},"channel_input_dirs":{"train":"/opt/ml/input/data/train"},"current_host":"algo-1","framework_module":"sagemaker_sklearn_container.training:main","hosts":["algo-1"],"hyperparameters":{"C":1.0,"class_weight":null,"dualbool":false,"fit_intercept":true,"intercept_scaling":1,"l1_ratio":null,"max_iter":1000,"multi_class":"auto","n_jobs":null,"penalty":"l2","random_state":null,"solver":"lbfgs","tol":0.0001,"verbose":0,"warm_start":false},"input_config_dir":"/opt/ml/input/config","input_data_config":{"train":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"}},"input_dir":"/opt/ml/input","is_master":true,"job_name":"logisticregression-model-2023-05-05-20-31-29-013","log_level":20,"master_hostname":"algo-1","model_dir":"/opt/ml/model","module_dir":"s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-457933018994/logisticregression-model-2023-05-05-20-31-29-013/source/sourcedir.tar.gz","module_name":"script","network_interface_name":"eth0","num_cpus":2,"num_gpus":0,"output_data_dir":"/opt/ml/output/data","output_dir":"/opt/ml/output","output_intermediate_dir":"/opt/ml/output/intermediate","resource_config":{"current_group_name":"homogeneousCluster","current_host":"algo-1","current_instance_type":"ml.m5.large","hosts":["algo-1"],"instance_groups":[{"hosts":["algo-1"],"instance_group_name":"homogeneousCluster","instance_type":"ml.m5.large"}],"network_interface_name":"eth0"},"user_entry_point":"script.py"}
SM_USER_ARGS=["-C","1.0","--class_weight","","--dualbool","False","--fit_intercept","True","--intercept_scaling","1","--l1_ratio","","--max_iter","1000","--multi_class","auto","--n_jobs","","--penalty","l2","--random_state","","--solver","lbfgs","--tol","0.0001","--verbose","0","--warm_start","False"]
SM_OUTPUT_INTERMEDIATE_DIR=/opt/ml/output/intermediate
SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN=/opt/ml/input/data/train
SM_HP_C=1.0
SM_HP_CLASS_WEIGHT=
SM_HP_DUALBOOL=false
SM_HP_FIT_INTERCEPT=true
SM_HP_INTERCEPT_SCALING=1
SM_HP_L1_RATIO=
SM_HP_MAX_ITER=1000
SM_HP_MULTI_CLASS=auto
SM_HP_N_JOBS=
SM_HP_PENALTY=l2
SM_HP_RANDOM_STATE=
SM_HP_SOLVER=lbfgs
SM_HP_TOL=0.0001
SM_HP_VERBOSE=0
SM_HP_WARM_START=false
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ml/code:/miniconda3/bin:/miniconda3/lib/python37.zip:/miniconda3/lib/python3.7:/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload:/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Invoking script with the following command:
/miniconda3/bin/python script.py -C 1.0 --class_weight  --dualbool False --fit_intercept True --intercept_scaling 1 --l1_ratio  --max_iter 1000 --multi_class auto --n_jobs  --penalty l2 --random_state  --solver lbfgs --tol 0.0001 --verbose 0 --warm_start False
usage: script.py [-h] [--penalty PENALTY] [--dualbool DUALBOOL] [--tol TOL]
                 [--C C] [--fit_intercept FIT_INTERCEPT]
                 [--intercept_scaling INTERCEPT_SCALING]
                 [--class_weight CLASS_WEIGHT] [--random_state RANDOM_STATE]
                 [--solver SOLVER] [--max_iter MAX_ITER]
                 [--multi_class MULTI_CLASS] [--verbose VERBOSE]
                 [--warm_start WARM_START] [--n_jobs N_JOBS]
                 [--l1_ratio L1_RATIO] [--train TRAIN] [--test TEST]
                 [--model_dir MODEL_DIR]
script.py: error: argument --l1_ratio: invalid float value: ''
2023-05-05 20:33:49,209 sagemaker-containers ERROR    Reporting training FAILURE
2023-05-05 20:33:49,210 sagemaker-containers ERROR    framework error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_trainer.py", line 84, in train
    entrypoint()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/training.py", line 39, in main
    train(environment.Environment())
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/training.py", line 35, in train
    runner_type=runner.ProcessRunnerType)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/entry_point.py", line 100, in run
    wait, capture_error
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/process.py", line 291, in run
    cwd=environment.code_dir,
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/process.py", line 208, in check_error
    info=extra_info,
sagemaker_training.errors.ExecuteUserScriptError: ExecuteUserScriptError:
ExitCode 2
ErrorMessage ""
Command "/miniconda3/bin/python script.py -C 1.0 --class_weight  --dualbool False --fit_intercept True --intercept_scaling 1 --l1_ratio  --max_iter 1000 --multi_class auto --n_jobs  --penalty l2 --random_state  --solver lbfgs --tol 0.0001 --verbose 0 --warm_start False"
ExecuteUserScriptError:
ExitCode 2
ErrorMessage ""
Command "/miniconda3/bin/python script.py -C 1.0 --class_weight  --dualbool False --fit_intercept True --intercept_scaling 1 --l1_ratio  --max_iter 1000 --multi_class auto --n_jobs  --penalty l2 --random_state  --solver lbfgs --tol 0.0001 --verbose 0 --warm_start False"

2023-05-05 20:34:04 Uploading - Uploading generated training model
2023-05-05 20:34:04 Failed - Training job failed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnexpectedStatusException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_9278/1459479382.py in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 estimator.fit(inputs)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sagemaker/workflow/pipeline_context.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    282             return _StepArguments(retrieve_caller_name(self_instance), run_func, *args, **kwargs)
    283 
--> 284         return run_func(*args, **kwargs)
    285 
    286     return wrapper

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in fit(self, inputs, wait, logs, job_name, experiment_config)
   1196         self.jobs.append(self.latest_training_job)
   1197         if wait:
-> 1198             self.latest_training_job.wait(logs=logs)
   1199 
   1200     def _compilation_job_name(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in wait(self, logs)
   2342         # If logs are requested, call logs_for_jobs.
   2343         if logs != "None":
-> 2344             self.sagemaker_session.logs_for_job(self.job_name, wait=True, log_type=logs)
   2345         else:
   2346             self.sagemaker_session.wait_for_job(self.job_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in logs_for_job(self, job_name, wait, poll, log_type)
   4754 
   4755         if wait:
-> 4756             self._check_job_status(job_name, description, "TrainingJobStatus")
   4757             if dot:
   4758                 print()

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in _check_job_status(self, job, desc, status_key_name)
   4261                     actual_status=status,
   4262                 )
-> 4263             raise exceptions.UnexpectedStatusException(
   4264                 message=message,
   4265                 allowed_statuses=["Completed", "Stopped"],

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job logisticregression-model-2023-05-05-20-31-29-013: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: framework error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_trainer.py", line 84, in train
    entrypoint()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/training.py", line 39, in main
    train(environment.Environment())
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/training.py", line 35, in train
    runner_type=runner.ProcessRunnerType)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/entry_point.py", line 100, in run
    wait, capture_error
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/process.py", line 291, in run
    cwd=environment.code_dir,
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/process.py", line 208, in check_error
    info=extra_info,
sagemaker_training.errors.ExecuteUserScriptError: ExecuteUserScriptError:
ExitCode 2
ErrorMessage ""
Command "/miniconda3/bin/python script.py -C 1.0 --class_weight
```

I have tried following the examples as best as I could but it does not want to work with logistic regression! it only works with the script's original algorithm LinearRegression and nothing I do seems to anything. I was following Mikegchambers tutorial on youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_AtgCm43Nk&t=730s the script he wrote was very simple and I thought that it would be easy to just change the algorithm and work from there.

this is the training script I have been trying to use:

```
%%writefile script/script.py

import argparse
import os
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pickle

def parse_args():
    """
    Parse arguments.
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # hyperparameters sent by the client are passed as command-line arguments to the script
    # We don't use these but I left them in as a useful template for future development
    #parser.add_argument("--copy_X",        type=bool, default=True)
    #parser.add_argument("--fit_intercept", type=bool, default=True)
    #parser.add_argument("--normalize",     type=bool, default=False)
    
    parser.add_argument("--penalty",           type=str,   default='l2')
    parser.add_argument("--dualbool",          type=bool,  default=False)
    parser.add_argument("--tol",               type=float, default=0.0001)
    parser.add_argument("--C",                 type=float, default=1.0)
    parser.add_argument("--fit_intercept",     type=bool,  default=True)
    parser.add_argument("--intercept_scaling", type=float, default=1)
    parser.add_argument("--class_weight", default=None)
    parser.add_argument("--random_state", default=None)
    parser.add_argument("--solver",       type=str,        default='lbfgs')
    parser.add_argument("--max_iter",     type=int,        default=100)
    parser.add_argument("--multi_class",  type=str,        default='auto')
    parser.add_argument("--verbose",      type=int,        default=0)
    parser.add_argument("--warm_start",   type=bool,       default=False)
    parser.add_argument("--n_jobs",       type=int,        default=None)
    parser.add_argument("--l1_ratio",     type=float,      default=None)
    
    # data directories
    parser.add_argument("--train", type=str, default=os.environ.get("SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN"))
    parser.add_argument("--test", type=str, default=os.environ.get("SM_CHANNEL_TEST"))

    # model directory: we will use the default set by SageMaker, /opt/ml/model
    parser.add_argument("--model_dir", type=str, default=os.environ.get("SM_MODEL_DIR"))

    return parser.parse_known_args()

def load_dataset(path):
    """
    Load entire dataset.
    """
    # Find all files with a pickle ext but we only load the first one in this sample:
    files = [os.path.join(path, file) for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith("pickle")]

    if len(files) == 0:
        raise ValueError("Invalid # of files in dir: {}".format(path))
    
    [X, y] = pickle.load(open(files[0], 'rb'))
    
    return X, y

def start(args):
    """
    Train Logistic Regression
    """
    print("Training mode")

    try:
        X_train, y_train = load_dataset(args.train)
        # X_test, y_test = load_dataset(args.test)

        hyperparameters = {
            "penalty": args.penalty,
            "dualbool": args.dualbool,
            "tol": args.tol,
            "C": args.C,
            "fit_intercept": args.fit_intercept,
            "intercept_scaling": args.intercept_scaling,
            #"class_weight": args.class_weight,
            #"random_state": args.random_state,
            "solver": args.solver,
            "max_iter": args.max_iter,
            "multi_class": args.multi_class,
            "verbose": args.verbose,
            "warm_start": args.warm_start,
            "n_jobs": args.n_jobs,
            "l1_ratio": args.l1_ratio
        }
        
        print("Training...")
        model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
        model.set_params(**hyperparameters)
                
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)

        pickle.dump(model, open(os.path.join(args.model_dir, "model.pickle"), 'wb'))
       

    except Exception as e:
        # Write out an error file. This will be returned as the failureReason in the
        # DescribeTrainingJob result.
        trc = traceback.format_exc()
        with open(os.path.join(output_path, "failure"), "w") as s:
            s.write("Exception during training: " + str(e) + "\\n" + trc)

        # Printing this causes the exception to be in the training job logs, as well.
        print("Exception during training: " + str(e) + "\\n" + trc, file=sys.stderr)

        # A non-zero exit code causes the training job to be marked as Failed.
        sys.exit(255)
        
def model_fn(model_dir):
    """
    Load the model for inference
    """
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(model_dir + "/model.pickle", 'rb'))
    return loaded_model


def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    """
    Apply model to the incoming request
    """
    return model.predict(input_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    args, _ = parse_args()

    start(args)
```

Update: I have applied what I thought would be a fix but the errors persist. I have changed all of the hyperparameters to what they should be but, I don't know if that is the actual cause of the problem, and if it is I don't know how to write the argparse for **class_weight** and **random_state**,

in the sklearn documentation, class_weight can accept a *dict*, the string 'balanced', or **None** and I have no idea how to account for those three seperate types when argparse's **type** only accepts one type. There are several other values in here that are the same way (random state accepts a **random_state** object and a few others).

Do I just need to try something else? is there a reason no one on the internet seems to be using SKlearns Logistic Regression on sagemaker? is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the version of SKLearn SageMaker Estimator that you are utilizing? You need to make sure this is compatible with the training script that you are passing. I would recommend locally trying to implement same operations and ensuring that the model trains as expected. Once you confirm the version make sure you are using that version with SKLearn SageMaker Estimator for your tuning/training job.

Comment: ok, The version of Sagemaker Notebook's SKlearn is 1.0 but the actual Sagemaker Estimator is version 0.23.1. I fixed that problem by properly specifying the Version number, but I ran into another one. it's saying that "scipy.sparse._csr" module not found. the version of the  Sagemaker estimator is 4 versions behind the one installed on the notebook. Am I supposed to update the premade Sagemaker Estimator?